# react-native-fbsdk The redirect_uri URL is not supported

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to use the react-native-fbsdk to allow users to log in to my app. I have set up a login button.

code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

export default class FBLoginButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert('Login failed with error: ' + error.message)
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert('Login was cancelled')
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                    (data) => {
                      console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                    }
                  )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert('User logged out')}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

When I click the login button I get this come up in the simulator

[image]

If i try to add permissions I get an xcode error:

code:

```
<LoginButton
          publishPermissions={['email']}
          onLoginFinished={...
```

error:
Thread1: signal SIGABRT

How do I get rid of the redirect_uri error?

Comment: Could these help: 1. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/ 2. https://www.janrain.com/blog/social-login-facebook-app-requires-strict-uri-matching? I mean, have you set or listed the redirect URI? You should also validate that the redirect is valid at all.

Comment: @zvona I haven't done anything with the redirect URI as you aren't supposed to need to when using react-native-fbsdk. I'm looking into that now but am struggling to connect the dots, when using it with react native. I don't know what redirect uri it is attempting to go to at all.

Comment: replace publishPermissions with readPermissions, this issue comes a lot to new react-native devs ;) you just used an old version prop name

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong `FacebookAppId` and `CFBundleURLSchemes` in the `info.plist` file in my `ios/appName/info.plist`. I had to go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/29476792337468632/fb-login/quickstart/?sdk=fbsdk to see what the APP ID is (it is displayed in the navigation bar next to your App name). The quickstart will actually give you the whole code block below with your correct app id to paste into info.plist.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb29476792337468632</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>29476792337468632</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>My App Name</string>
```